# Powershell - how extract dataset row with item like string

Tags: powershell, datasetvalue

I have a query that fills a dataset in powershell.  I'm trying to figure out how to use the dataset to extract the row that has a value like "ERROR".  I need to do that for a couple hundred strings for the query results.  I'm having trouble finding examples for this.

I know I can just iterate through the entire datset to get this info, but there should be a more succinct way to do this.

```
    $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;User Id=$username;Password=$password;" 
    $con = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection($connectionString) 
    $query =  Get-Content $sqlPath #"select * from SEVERITY_TBL" 
    $con.open()
    $dtSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $OracleAdapter = New-Object System.Data.OracleClient.OracleDataAdapter($query,$con)
    $recordCount = $OracleAdapter.Fill($dtSet)
    Write-Host "Count: $recordCount" -ForegroundColor Cyan #prints 2784
    $data = $dtSet.Tables[0]

    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable("one")
    $dt2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable($dt)
    $dt.Columns.Add("SEVERITYNAME")
    $dt.Columns.Add("COMPONENTNAME")
    $dt.Columns.Add("COMPONENTSTATECODE")
    foreach ($dr in $data)
    {
        $row = $dt.NewRow()
        Write-Host($dr.ItemArray)
        $row['SEVERITYNAME'] = $dr.ItemArray[6]
        $row['COMPONENTNAME'] = $dr.ItemArray[3]
        $row['COMPONENTSTATECODE'] = $dr.ItemArray[5]
        #Write-Host($dr.ItemArray[0])
        Write-Host("severity:",$row.SEVERITYNAME)
        $dt.Rows.Add($row)
        #Write-Host($dr.ItemArray['SEVERITYNAME'])
    }

    $dt2 = $dt | Select-Object SEVERITYNAME, COMPONENTNAME, COMPONENTSTATECODE | Where-Object {$_.SEVERITYNAME -Match 'Warning'} | Where-Object {$_.COMPONENTSTATECODE -Match "ERROR"} #I can't figure out how to assign this to a variable so I can look at it, but from what I can see, it's not filtering the query data like I'm telling it to...
```

Query results look like this:

```
DeviceType  Version  CompTypeName  ComponentName        ComponentStateCode          SeverityName
FirstOne    Current  Apps          Company Monitoring   Archive.OutOfMaterial       Normal
SecondOne   Current  Apps          Application Sec      Archive.Error               Warning
```

What is a good way to use my query results and look up a "ERROR", so I can get if it's "Warning" or whatever the severityname value is?

I was looking at [row lines from powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/19a161f6-d996-4aa9-8ea4-e1df3182b11a/reading-multiple-row-lines-from-query-in-power-shell?forum=winserverpowershell),
and also [column equals value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96876/powershell-get-all-items-where-column-equals-a-certain-value),
and also [datatable select string](https://www.dbtales.com/powershell-datatable-select-distinct-or-unique-values/).

Any help would be appreciated! I'm using Powershell 5.1 and visual studio code.

Comment: So you have a value `"ERROR"`, and you want to use that to find the row that has `ComponentStateCode` value of `Archive.Error`, and then output the `SeverityName` of that row? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - It's more like I need to use Archive.Error to look up Warning.

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like `$dt2 = $dt | Where-Object {$_.SEVERITYNAME -ne 'Normal' -and $_.COMPONENTSTATECODE -Match "Error"} | Select-Object SEVERITYNAME, COMPONENTNAME, COMPONENTSTATECODE` ?

Comment: @Theo - thank you! I was able to return $dt2 from my function (not shown), and then apply the expression you shared and $dt2 had the correct data in it after that.  Before $dt2 didn't have the correct data in it, maybe because of the order I did things in.